# How to get offset between last point of series and left corner of chart

Tags: lightningchart

I have a chart that is filled with content from HTTP requests. And data always come with this code

```
 chartComponent.chartInstance
      .getDefaultAxisX()
      .onAxisInteractionAreaMouseDragStop((axis: Axis, event: MouseEvent, button: number, startLocation: Point): void => {
        if (axis.getInterval().start / 2 < 10000) {
          this.chartService.loadHistorySeriesData(chartComponent.selectedTimeRangeMinutes).subscribe((data: SeriesMapResponse) => {
            this.chartService.addNewDataToTheSeriesInstances(chartComponent.chartId, chartComponent.seriesInstances);
          })
        }
      })
```

So I have to implement conditions like if the offset is less than some number load me new data... Like pagination on the Instagram feed but with carts. How can I get this offset, I tried a lot of approaches and nothing works.

Comment: I suppose this question is not directly about LightningChart JS, but rather how to implement a specific type of data loading behavior? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @NiiloKeinänen the text about data receiving was for a better understanding of why I need to get offset. But the main goal of my question is how I can get offset from the last point (for the vertical chart this last point from the left) and the left side of the chart. And if offset less than some value I should load new data. For a better understanding of what I mean I [attached screenshot](https://ibb.co/fDQ55Kt)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "left side of chart" information by referencing the X Axis interval start, like follows:

`Axis.getInterval().start`

You can probably get the needed information of "last old point" by `LineSeries.getXMin()` method.